# Gateway timeout caused by simple CGI script

Tags: apache, cgi

I have a simple CGI script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("<form name='mainform' method='POST' action='http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi>'>";
    printf("<h2>Hello, world!</h2>");
     printf("<button type='submit' name='submitbtn'>Submit</button>");
     printf("</form>");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it from web browser's URL bar everything works well. But when I press "SUBMIT", then the status bar 'Waiting for localhost' appears followed by '504 Gateway Time-out' error

Answer (score 0):

Every hello world CGI I've seen issues a Content-Type followed by CRLF CRLF. You can't just spit out HTML.

Update: You'll also need to read stdin (the POST body) to EOF when the action is submitted.

Comment: Thanx, covener. I added Content-Type followed by CRLF CRLF. But again, when I run the script from browser URL bar it works. But when I press the submit button, the same "Gateway timeout" error appears

Comment: Try reading stdin to exhaustion to handle the post that occurs.